# php is_numeric zero filled strings (0000018)

Tags: php

I have tested `is_numeric` on zero filled ints such 0000018 and it return true. The documentation says:

> "Finds whether the given variable is numeric. Numeric strings consist
>   of optional sign, any number of digits, optional decimal part and
>   optional exponential part. Thus +0123.45e6 is a valid numeric value.
>   Hexadecimal (e.g. 0xf4c3b00c), Binary (e.g. 0b10100111001), Octal
>   (e.g. 0777) notation is allowed too but only without sign, decimal and
>   exponential part."

Would this fall under the any number of digits part?

Comment: Why would it return false? `is_numeric(0000018)` must return true, otherwise I haven't got your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both cases (string and the (invalid)octal number) will return true:

```
var_dump( is_numeric("0000018") );  //bool(true)
var_dump( is_numeric(0000018) );    //bool(true)
```

In the first case it's just a numeric string.

A quote from the manual ([`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)):

> Returns TRUE if var is a number **or a numeric string**, FALSE otherwise.

In the second case it is a octal number, just a invalid one, so this will happen (From the manual [`Integer`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)):

> **Warning:**
>   If an invalid digit is given in an octal integer (i.e. 8 or 9), the **rest of the number is ignored**.

Means in this case:

```
0000018 -> 000001 -> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

'this' being the 0000018? Any number of digits would be any, but certainly would be more than 16 digits. I think your question is too broad and doesn't have a specific solution, it's more of a discussion piece.